# BufferedInputStream is closed when setting postDelayed Runnable

Tags: java, android, json

I have my GameActivity that is a simple quiz. I set up two Runnables, `mRunnableQuestion` and `mRunnableQuestionWithPenalty`. The logic is: `mRunnableQuestion` shows new question and waits 30 seconds, when user doesn't answer in this time, the other Runnable is called, which gives user points penalty:

```
private Runnable mRunnableQuestion = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new AsyncAPIGetQuestion().execute(mCategoryId);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnableQuestionWithPenalty, 30000);
    }
};
```

Of course, when user answers in time, I give user points and restart the Runnable:

```
mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
mHandler.post(mRunnableQuestion);
```

It works very well. However, I wanted to color the Cards based on correct/wrong answer and wait 5 seconds. So i changed code above to:

```
mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
colorAnswers();
mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnableQuestion, 5000);
```

This is where the problem begins. When I run my app, after 2, 3 or 4 questions I get a EOF/BufferedInputStream error:

```
    03-04 13:38:24.107 16506-16532/com.my.pkg W/System.err: java.io.EOFException
    03-04 13:38:24.107 16506-16532/com.my.pkg W/System.err:     at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:95)
    03-04 13:38:24.107 16506-16532/com.my.pkg W/System.err:     at com.
    android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:175)
    03-04 13:38:24.107 16506-16532/com.my.pkg W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:101)
    03-04 13:38:24.107 16506-16532/com.my.pkg W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:616)
    03-04 13:38:24.107 16506-16532/com.my.pkg W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:379)
    03-04 13:38:24.107 16506-16532/com.my.pkg W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
    03-04 13:38:24.108 16506-16532/com.my.pkg W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:190)
    03-04 13:38:24.108 16506-16532/com.my.pkg W/System.err:     at com.my.pkg.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:45)
    03-04 13:38:24.108 16506-16532/com.my.pkg W/System.err:     at com.my.pkg.GameActivity$AsyncAPIGetQuestion.doInBackground(GameActivity.java:317)
    03-04 13:38:24.108 16506-16532/com.my.pkg W/System.err:     at com.my.pkg.GameActivity$AsyncAPIGetQuestion.doInBackground(GameActivity.java:299)
    03-04 13:38:24.108 16506-16532/com.my.pkg W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    03-04 13:38:24.108 16506-16532/com.my.pkg W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    03-04 13:38:24.108 16506-16532/com.my.pkg W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    03-04 13:38:24.108 16506-16532/com.my.pkg W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    03-04 13:38:24.108 16506-16532/com.my.pkg W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    03-04 13:38:24.108 16506-16532/com.my.pkg W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    03-04 13:38:24.108 16506-16532/com.my.pkg E/JSONParser.java: Error converting result java.io.IOException: BufferedInputStream is closed
```

It ONLY happens, when I add the extra `postDelayed()` there. No problems before.

My doInBackground part of AsyncTask that is executed by Runnable and that returns an error as stated above

```
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(apiURL);
        return json;
    }
```

And the `JSONParser.getJSONFromURL`:

```
public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String urlSource) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlSource);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
            if(!reader.ready()) {
                break;
            }
        }
        inputStream.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {
        jArr = new JSONArray(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jArr;
}
```

I would really appreciate any help. All the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I solved this issue.

The problem was in my `jParser.getJSONFromUrl()` method, specifically these lines:

```
URL url = new URL(urlSource);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
```

It seems that you *only* set `setDoOutput` parameter as `true`, when you are using POST/PUT requests. If you want only perform a GET request, such as in my case, you *should set it as false*:

```
urlConnection.setDoOutput(false);
```

Otherwise, you can end up getting errors as described above.

Best regards to the Community!